# GitPython pipe output to stdout

Tags: python, git, scripting, gitpython

Doing some very simple scripting in python. I'm cloning the repository to the server with the following statement in a python script:

```
Repo.clone_from("source", "target")
```

How can I get the progress from the clone_from and pipe it to stdout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`git.remote.RemoteProgress`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#git.remote.RemoteProgress) as third parameter for the class method [`clone_from(url, to_path, progress=None, env=None, **kwargs)`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.clone_from) you are using:

```
class Progress(RemoteProgress):
    def line_dropped(self, line):
        print line
    def update(self, *args):
        print self._cur_line
```